# Парсинг Json, помощь новичку

Tags: java, android, json, парсер

Добрый вечер, получил json с внешнего ресурса, теперь хочу достать значение из "rates"(в идеале положить rates в Map), как это сделать? Спасибо.

JSON файл

```
{"base":"EUR","date":"2017-09-26","rates":{"AUD":1.4944,"BGN":1.9558,"BRL":3.7299,"CAD":1.4605,"CHF":1.1452,"CNY":7.8189,"CZK":26.056,"DKK":7.4404,"GBP":0.87775,"HKD":9.2083,"HRK":7.493,"HUF":310.77,"IDR":15785.0,"ILS":4.1579,"INR":77.194,"JPY":131.99,"KRW":1341.6,"MXN":21.182,"MYR":4.9662,"NOK":9.2843,"NZD":1.6369,"PHP":60.018,"PLN":4.2824,"RON":4.6013,"RUB":67.987,"SEK":9.5473,"SGD":1.5968,"THB":39.139,"TRY":4.1739,"USD":1.1787,"ZAR":15.733}}
```

Java код

```
   package vadimkonyuh.test;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String LOG_TAG = "my_log";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new ParseTask().execute();
    }

    private class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String resultJson = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // получаем данные с внешнего ресурса
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://api.fixer.io/latest");

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                resultJson = buffer.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return resultJson;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
            super.onPostExecute(strJson);
            // выводим целиком полученную json-строку
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, strJson);

             try {
                JSONObject
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Берите либу Gson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try{
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
 JSONObject c = jsonObj.getJSONObject("rates");
 String id = c.getString("AUD");
 String name = c.getString("BGN")



}
```

И вот на будущее

Создайте`JSONObject` :

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

Чтобы получить определенную строку

```
String aJsonString = jObject.getString("STRINGNAME");
```

Чтобы получить конкретное логическое значение

```
boolean aJsonBoolean = jObject.getBoolean("BOOLEANNAME");
```

Чтобы получить конкретное целое число

```
int aJsonInteger = jObject.getInt("INTEGERNAME");
```

Чтобы получить конкретный длинный

```
long aJsonLong = jObject.getBoolean("LONGNAME");
```

Чтобы получить конкретную двойную

```
double aJsonDouble = jObject.getDouble("DOUBLENAME");
```

Чтобы получить конкретный JSONArray :

```
JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("ARRAYNAME");
```

Чтобы получить элементы из массива

```
for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
{
    try {
        JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        // Pulling items from the array
        String oneObjectsItem = oneObject.getString("STRINGNAMEinTHEarray");
        String oneObjectsItem2 = oneObject.getString("anotherSTRINGNAMEINtheARRAY");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // Oops
    }
}
```

Comment: at rates of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: Попробуйте так пожалуйста

Comment: @ВадиКонюх а как насчет поставить палец вверх и прнять ответ ?

Comment: @elik, так ведь вы не то ответили. Нужно было все значения из `rates` положить в `Map`, ясно дело, что там могут быть разные значения и ключи. А вы оставили код типа `вот я по двум ключам взял, теперь ты сам все 100500+ сделаешь`

Comment: @flippy слово в идеале трактуется как желательно но не обезательно.Тебе тс подарить на днюху?)а то худо у тебя

Comment: @elik сейчас проверю и поставлю, помощь всегда оценю)

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с [gson](https://github.com/google/gson):

```
class Rates {
  String base;
  String date;
  Map<String, Double> rates;
}

Rates newRates = new Gson().fromJson(resultJson, Rates.class);
Log.d("",newRates.rates.get("CZK"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Код вот, набросал. Только проверить не могу, отпишитесь

```
String response = /*ответ от сервера*/;
HashMap<String, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
JSONObject rates = new JSONObject(response).getJSONObject("rates");
Iterator<?> keys = rates.keys();
while(keys.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String) keys.next();
    double value = rates.getDouble(key);
    map.put(key, value);
}
```

Comment: А как Retrofit, Volley и OkHttp помогут при смене конфигурации устройства?

Comment: Ругается на  double value = rates.get(key);

Comment: Ругается на double value = rates.get(key); Нужно было double value = rates.getDouble(key); 
Большое спасибо) На stackoverflow есть личка? Хотел задать пару вопросов опытному android разработчику)

Comment: @post_zeew, да, точно, фигню написал

Answer (score -2):

должно помочь
https://github.com/wnameless/json-flattener

Так же советую почитать о библиотеке для тестирования API - https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage

там полный экскурс не тему тестирования и парсинга json и xml

Comment: "должно помочь" - а вы помочь не можете?